# Get the first date and time from within a group

Tags: mdx

Many of the questions we get asked are related to how much time passes between two events (e.g. - patient was admitted, some assessment occurred). Some events take place multiple times. How can I find the first date and time that an event occurred per patient visit?

In the model is a table called Clinical Queries. In that table is a column called Activity Date Time. There is a calculated column called Date and another called Time that are based off of the Activity Date Time. These are related to a Date dimension table and a Time dimension table.

I've managed to build a query that gives me the earliest date, and it gives me the earliest time. However, it returns the earliest time regardless of the date. For example, if a patient has two assessments performed, one on 1/1/2017 at 23:59 and another on 1/2/2017 at 00:01, the query returns 1/1/2017 at 00:01.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[FirstInterventionDate] AS (
    NonEmpty(existing{[Date].[Fiscal].[Date].MEMBERS}, {[Measures].[Clinical Queries Interventions Performed]}).Item(0).Name
)

MEMBER [Measures].[FirstInterventionTime] AS (
    NonEmpty(existing{[Time].[Time].[Time].MEMBERS}, {[Measures].[Clinical Queries Interventions Performed]}).Item(0).Name
)

SELECT {[Measures].[Clinical Queries Interventions Performed], [Measures].[FirstInterventionDate], [Measures].[FirstInterventionTime]} on 0,
    NON EMPTY([Clinical Queries].[Account Number].Children) ON 1
FROM (
SELECT { [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000195],
    [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000186],
    [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000184],
    [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000182],
    [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000184] } ON 0
FROM (
SELECT { [Clinical Queries].[Account Number].&[ACCT992],
    [Clinical Queries].[Account Number].&[ACCT064] } ON 0
FROM [Model]
))
```

What do I need to change to make it return the earliest date and time for that earliest date. For the example above it would be 1/1/2017 at 23:59.

Comment: If you want good performance then add the ActivityDateTime column to your fact table and put a AggregateFunction=Min measure over it. That will be way more efficient than any possible MDX option.

Comment: I added a min aggregation measure as you and Danylo both suggested and it's working great! I'm still trying to get my SQL mind wrapped around multidimenional concepts. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
select 
    {[Clinical Queries].[Account Number].&[ACCT992],
     [Clinical Queries].[Account Number].&[ACCT064]} *
    {[Measures].[Clinical Queries Interventions Performed]} on 0,
    Generate(
        {[Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000195],
         [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000186],
         [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000184],
         [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000182],
         [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].&[3000184]},
        Head(
            NonEmpty(
                [Clinical Queries].[InterventionID].CurrentMember *
                [Date].[Fiscal].[Date].Members *
                [Time].[Time].[Time].Members,
                [Measures].[Clinical Queries Interventions Performed]
            ),
            1
        )
    ) on 1
from [Model]
```

You may be not very happy about performance, so I strongly recommend you to move the logic on DWH level: add a measure field like 201703301020 (3/30/2017 10:20) with **Min** aggregation, you may parse the value using MDX calculated measure combined with left() right() functions.